# Can I add a method to a function to receive as an argument another particular function?

Tags: julia

I've created my immutable `Tensor_field` and a function `nabla` that acts on the tensor (that is `nabla(a::Tensor_field) = do something`.

I've added a method to function `dot` for the tensor: `Base.dot(a::Tensor_field, b::Tensor_field) = do something...`.

Now I want to define a new behavior to function `dot` with `nabla` as an argument. 
Something like  `Base.dot(nabla::function, a::Tensor_field) = do something different`.

I know in Julia we are able to pass functions as arguments to other functions, but I couldn't find in the docs how to define a method for a "functional" argument.

If I type `typeof(nabla)` the output is `My_Module_Name.#nabla`, not a real DataType...

Comment: Just to clarify: `My_Module_Name.#nabla` _is_ a real DataType. The name is weird and can't be accessed normally (because `#` starts a comment) but can still be accessed through `getfield(My_Module_Name, Symbol("#nabla"))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to work for *any* function, you can do

```
Base.dot(f::Function, a::Tensor_field) = do something different
```

If you *only* want it to work for the `nabla` function already defined, you can take advantage of what you have discovered, namely that each function has a unique type:

```
Base.dot(f::typeof(nabla), a::Tensor_field) = do something different
```

This will match *only* the function called `nabla`, which will now be called `f` inside the function `dot`.

Note that you can write ∇ as `\nabla<TAB>` and use it in your code instead of the word `nabla`. If your tensor field is called e.g.  (written as `\mbfv<TAB>`), you can then write `∇⋅` in your Julia code! (The centered dot is written as `\cdot<TAB>`, and is an alias for the `dot` function.)